# Open-source software for printing calendar months (with a printer)

Tags: linux, calendar, printing

I'm wanting a program for Linux (I use Xubuntu) where I can print calendars (with a printer; I don't just mean printing it to the screen). It would be nice if I could add events to it before printing, too. I'd also like to be able to print a full year calendar on one page (which wouldn't require events—just the mini calendar things they use for next/previous months usually).

Have you found anything like this, especially that you can get via apt-get?

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can print calendars (with a printer as onto sheets of paper) with Evolution (which is an email client, but it also has calendar software bundled in). It also allows you to print pages of a month that include custom-made events on it, too. The monthly pages include mini calendars for the next and previous months, too. They're fairly simple, but they look nice.

You can download it by doing `sudo apt-get install evolution`.

I don't know that Evolution has the option to print yearly calendars of any sort. I don't see the option.